# Writing code for power module in c++, receiving several errors

Tags: c++

I'm writing code that doesn't use pow() in c++, but I am getting quite a few errors which I can't figure out:

```
double power (double X, unsigned int N)
{
    double value;
    unsigned int i = 1;
    for (i = 1, i <= N, i++)
    {
        result = result * X;
    }

    if (finite(result))
    {
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return INFINITY;
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
In function 'double power(double, unsigned int)':
Line 5: warning: right-hand operand of comma has no effect
Line 5: error: expected ';' before ')' token
Line 10: error: expected primary-expression before 'if'
Line 10: error: expected ';' before 'if'
Line 10: error: expected primary-expression before 'if'
Line 10: error: expected ')' before 'if'
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Fix your `for` syntax first (semicolons `;` instead of commas `,`)

Comment: I would also give `result` an initial value before multiplying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `for (i = 1; i <= N; i++)`.

In C++, the semicolon is usd to delimit the different parts of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

1. `for (i = 1, i <= N, i++)` => `for (i = 1; i <= N; i++)`
2. Get a good C book